# web scraping with selenium phantom js or python requests - every 2-3 pages server returns 'bad' page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I've been scrping happily with selenium/phantom js. Recently, I noticed that one of the websites I am scraping, started returning a 'bad' page (page with no relevant content every 2-3 pages) - not clear why. I tested with python requests and I am getting similar results (issues) although it is slightly better (more like 3-4 pages before I get a bad one).

What I do:

1. I have a page url list that I shuffle - so it is unlikely to have the same scraping pattern.
2. I have a random 10-20 seconds sleep between requests (none of it is urgent)
3. I tried with **and** without cookies
4. I tried rotating IP addresses (bounce my server between scrapes and get new IP address)
5. I checked robots.txt - not doing anything 'bad'
6. User agent is set in a similar manner to what I get on my laptop (http://whatsmyuseragent.com/)
7. phantomjs desired capabilities set to a dictionary identical to DesiredCapabilities.CHROME (I actually created my own Chrome dictionary and embedded the real chrome version I am using).
8. JavaScript enabled (although I do not really need it)
9. I set ignore ssl errors using `service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true']`

I only run the scrape twice a day ~9 hours apart. Issues are the same whether I run the code on my laptop or on Ubuntu somewhere in the cloud.

Thoughts?

Comment: I faced the same issue and I noticed they had api-keys as part of request headers and the api-key expires after certain some time.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is throttling or blocking you, you need to contact the admin of the server and ask him to whitelist you.
There is nothing you can do except trying to scrape even slower.

If the server is overloaded you could try different times of the day. If the server is bugged, try to reproduce it and inform the admin.

Comment: Interesting. How/why am I being blocked when IP addresses changes/vary? Is there anything in what I'm doing that continuously says 'hey guys, it's me again'? Also, tried sleep times in excess of  10 mins. No difference :(

Comment: Then it might really be a server bug or limit. You will have to retry if it fails.